# How to get Documents from sharepoint Document Library passing parameters?

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api

I have one document library, in that, I have multiple folders.

For example:

- Foldername1/Foldername2/Foldername3/Text.docx
- Foldername1/Text.docx
- Foldername1/foldernmae2/Text.docx

In which folder user want to upload document they can upload.

In this images inside 18 Folder I am having Award, Closeout, and rfp.
Inside these 3, I have Documents, Miscellneous, Request for proposal. Inside this I have 64 and 67.

I want to retrive the file from particular folder passing Foldernames

This is my code :

```
function GetDocumentName(strContractNumber, strChecklistName) {
        //in this url i want to pass strContractNumber and strChecklistName
        url = '/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'Documents\')/Items?$expand=Folder&$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef&$filter=FileLeafRef eq \'' + strContractNumber + '\'';
       alert(url)
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
            },
            async: false,

            url: url,


            success: function (data) {
            $.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {
              var s = item.FileLeafRef;
             });
            },

            error: function (data) {
            }
        });

    }
```

In the url, I have to pass the strContractNumber(18) and strChecklistName(Award). Now I want to get the Test.docx document name and store that document name in one string.

I tried this but is not working

```
url = '/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(\'Documents\')/Folders';
```

How can i acheive this?

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is:

```
/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/Shared Documents/Folder A')/files
```

reference: [MSDN FileCollection resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#Anchor_3)

By the way you are calling the api like this:

```
url = '/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'Contract CheckList Documents\')/Items?$expand=Folder&$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef&$filter=FileLeafRef eq \'' + strContractNumber + '\'';
```

Try this:

```
url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +'/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl(\'Contract CheckList Documents\')/files?$expand=Folder&$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef&$filter=FileLeafRef eq \'' + strContractNumber + '\'';
```

If your site is http://sharepoint.local/sites/site then you have to call like this:

```
url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +'/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl(\'sites/site/Contract CheckList Documents\')/files?$expand=Folder&$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef&$filter=FileLeafRef eq \'' + strContractNumber + '\'';
```

In my case the uri will be:

```
url = "http://vmsps2013/gestor/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('Documents')/files"
```

and return this:
[image]

Comment: I was tried this but is not working how can i get the file name and store it in string.

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: Hi marco in that url i want to pass the string values.First i want to pass 18(Foldername) after i want to pass Award. Then i want to get the Test.docx document. var filename = data.d.Fileref. In filename i want Test.docx name. how can i do this ?

Comment: I tried like this
getFoldername = Documents/18

url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/' + '_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(' + getFoldername + ')/files';

in alert my url coming like this
http://mysiteurl/_api/web/GetfolderbyServerRelativeUrl(Documents/18)/Files
but i did not get result

Comment: I edited my answer